# Different definitions of homogeneous polynomials

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $k$ be an infinite field of positive characteristic, let $0\ne f(X_1,...,X_n)\in k[X_1,...,X_n]$ be such that $f(cX_1,...,cX_n)=c^df(X_1,...,X_n), \forall c \in k$. Then we can see that $d=\deg f$ . My question is : Can we conclude that $f$ is a sum of monomials of equal degree($d$) ?

I can see it if $\operatorname{char}k=0$.

Considering the polynomial

$$F(X_1,...,X_n,X_{n+1})=f(X_{n+1}X_1,...,X_{n+1}X_n)-X_{n+1}^df(X_1,...,X_n) \in k[X_1,...,X_n,X_{n+1}],$$

since $F(c_1,...,c_n,c_{n+1})=0,\forall c_1,...,c_{n+1}\in k^{n+1}$, and $k$ is infinite, it is clear that

$f(X_{n+1}X_1,...,X_{n+1}X_n)=X_{n+1}^df(X_1,...,X_n)$ in $k[X_1,...,X_n,X_{n+1}] $. I am unable to get anything else. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Decompose $f=g_0+g_1+...+g_n$, where each $g_k$ has monomials of degree $k$ only. Compose with $cX$ for infinitely many $c$'s. "Solve" for $g_k$ (you should get that $g_k=0$ for $k\neq d$).

Comment: What argument do you have in characteristic $0$ that doesn't work in positive characteristic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ have degree $m$ and let $f_i$ be the degree $i$ homogeneous piece of $f$, so $f=f_0+f_1+\dots+f_m$.  Note then that $$f(X_{n+1}X_1,\dots,X_{n+1}X_n)=f_0(X_1,\dots,X_n)+X_{n+1}f_1(X_1,\dots,X_n)+\dots+X_{n+1}^mf_m(X_1,\dots,X_m).$$  Note also that no cancellation can occur between the terms on the right side, since they all have different powers of $X_{n+1}$.  Since $f(X_{n+1}X_1,\dots,X_{n+1}X_n)=X_{n+1}^df(X_1,\dots,X_n)$, the only nonzero term in the equation above is $X_{n+1}^df(X_1,\dots,X_n)$.  This means exactly that $f_i=0$ for $i\neq d$ and $f=f_d$, so $f$ is homogeneous of degree $d$.